# EJS and conditional statements

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, logic, ejs

See the error below. I'm using EJS "^3.1.5" with express "^4.17.1" and typescript. Why is EJS not evaluating to the else branch?

```
ReferenceError: /home/pauld/tscript/dist/views/index.ejs:12
    10| </head>
    11| <body>
 >> 12| <%- include("./partials/nav"), {user: user} %>
    13|     <div class="container">
    14|         <h1 class="header">Header</h1>
    15|         <a class="btn" href="/start"><i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i>Get started!</a>

/home/pauld/tscript/dist/views/partials/nav.ejs:4
    2|     <div class="nav-wrapper">
    3|         <a href="/" class="brand-logo">
 >> 4|  <% if ( user ) { %>
    5|          <%= user.name %>'s 
    6|  <% } else { %>
    7|          Anonymous

user is not defined
at eval (/home/pauld/tscript/dist/views/partials/nav.ejs:12:8)
    at nav (/home/pauld/tscript/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:691:17)
    at include (/home/pauld/tscript/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:689:39)
    at eval (/home/pauld/tscript/dist/views/index.ejs:12:17)
```

---

Update:

If I update line 12 per Russopotomus to this:

```
<%- include("./partials/nav", {user: user}) %>
```

Then I get the same error with a slightly different stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: /home/pauld/tscript/dist/views/index.ejs:12
    10| </head>
    11| <body>
 >> 12| <%- include("./partials/nav", {user: user}) %>
    13|     <div class="container">
    14|         <h1 class="header">Header</h1>
    15|         <a class="btn" href="/start"><i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i>Get started!</a>

user is not defined
    at eval (/home/pauld/tscript/dist/views/index.ejs:12:50)
    at index (/home/pauld/tscript/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:691:17)
```

...

In other words, it doesn't include the bit with the partial.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
<%- include("./partials/nav"), {user: user} %>
```

You must pass the render data as a parameter to the include function call:

```
<%- include("./partials/nav", {user: user}) %>
```

(In case it is unclear - the position of the round bracket `)` has changed)

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. This time I only get the error from index.ejs, not the partial nav.ejs.

Comment: I added the details above!

Comment: Can you include the code where the 'index' template is rendered? I'm guessing you are not passing `user` into that correctly.

Comment: So, this was the issue. I was following this tutorial. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/11/15/node-express-typescript . it only works with ejs 2.x , whereas I had installed ejs 3.x for security reasons. Thanks Russopotomus.